# Metric $d(\sigma,\tau)$ in $S_{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces, permutations

Let $S_{n}$ denote the set of permutations of the sequence from $(1,2,\dots,n)$.
Let us define a metric on $S_{n}$ for any $\sigma, \tau\in S_{n}$, such that $$d(\sigma,\tau)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vert\sigma(i)-\tau(i)\vert$$. What are the values of $d(\sigma,\tau)$ can be?

Any ideas from which point should I start?

Comment: I would start with $\sigma$ a cycle and $\tau$ the identity.

Comment: Can it ever be negative? Can it ever be non-integer? How large can it be for a fixed $n$? The best way to get a grip on this is to do a few calculations yourself.

Comment: First, observe that $d\left(\sigma, \tau\right) = d\left(1, \tau \circ \sigma^{-1}\right)$, where $1$ denotes $\operatorname{id}$. Thus, it suffices to understand $d\left(1, \pi\right)$ for all permutations $\pi$. But $d\left(1, \pi\right)$ is the *total displacement* of $\pi$, and equals twice the *depth* of $\pi$, studied in [arXiv:1202.4765v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4765v3). From Proposition 3.2 in that paper, you can conclude that $d\left(\sigma, \tau\right)$ is an even integer between $0$ and $2\left\lfloor n^2/4\right\rfloor$. Suspecting that all such integers are actually reached.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but too long for a comment:

Let $D_n$ be the range of $d$ under $S_n$. A quick and dirty implementation in python

```
import itertools
n = 4
domain = range(1, n+1)
perm = list(itertools.permutations(domain))
values = set()

for i in perm:
    for j in perm:
        x = 0
        for k in range (0, n):
            x += abs(i[k] -j[k])
        values.add(x)

return values
```

yields that
$$
\begin{align*}
D_1 &= \{0\} \\
D_2 &= \{0,2 \} \\
D_3 &= \{0,2,4 \} \\
D_4 &= \{0,2,4, 6, 8\} \\
D_5 &= \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12 \} \\
D_6 &= \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 \} \\
D_7 &= \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24 \}
\end{align*}
$$

It's also easy to show that $D_n \subseteq D_{n+1}$ and that $\{0,2, \ldots, 2 \cdot (n-1) \} \subseteq D_{n+1}$ (for all $n$). However, I'm not sure where the extra values in the steps $3 \mapsto 4$, $4 \mapsto 5$, $5 \mapsto 6$, $6 \mapsto 7$ come from.

Comment: If you take the difference between the identity and "reverse" permutations you get a value of $2n^2 \in D_{2n}$ and $2n(n+1) \in D_{2n+1}$ which seems to match the maximum values you got.

Comment: The maximum value is [OEIS A007590](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C12%2C18%2C24&language=english&go=Search)

Answer (score 1):

The value of $d(\sigma,\tau)$ can be any even integer between $0$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}n^2\right\rfloor$. In fact, given an even integer $k$ within these bounds, one can explicitly construct a permutation $\sigma$ with $d(\sigma,Id)=k$, where $Id$ denotes the identity permutation (we will abuse the notation slightly and use the same name for all identity permutations, regardless of the value of $n$).

We will prove this in an induction-like fashion:

- If $n\leq 2$, the problem is trivial. From now on, we'll assume $n\geq 3$.
- If $k < 2(n-1)$, we can deduce that $k\leq 2(n-1)-2$ (due to $k$ being an even integer) and a short calculation tells us that:
  $$\begin{eqnarray}
  0 & \leq & (n-3)^2 \\
  0 & \leq & (n-1)^2 - 4n + 8\\
  2(n-1) - 2 & \leq & \frac{1}{2}(n-1)^2 \\
  k & \leq & \left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(n-1)^2\right\rfloor \\
  \end{eqnarray}$$
  where the floor function could have been introduced thanks to the left-hand side of the inequality being an integer. The last inequality allows us to apply the induction hypothesis to obtain a permutation $\sigma$ on $(n-1)$ elements having $d(\sigma,Id)=k$ and extend it by setting $\sigma(n)=n$ to obtain a permutation on $n$ elements with the desired property.
- Finally, if $k\geq 2(n-1)$, we find a permutation $\sigma'$ on $(n-2)$ elements with $d(\sigma',Id)=k-2(n-1)$ by the induction hypothesis. This can be done because $$\begin{eqnarray}
  k-2(n-1) & \leq & \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2}n^2\right\rfloor - 2(n-1)\\
  & = & \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2}\left(n^2 - 4n + 4\right)\right\rfloor\\
  & = & \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2}\left(n-2\right)^2\right\rfloor
  \end{eqnarray}$$
  Now, we can define our permutation $\sigma$ as $\sigma(1)=n$, $\sigma(n)=1$ and $\sigma(i)=\sigma'(i-1)+1$ for $1<i<n$. Doing so gives us $d(\sigma,Id)=(n-1)+d(\sigma',Id)+(n-1)=k$.

This completes the proof that any even value between $0$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}n^2\right\rfloor$ is a distance between some pair of permutations.

Note that this chain of reasoning does *not* show that a value larger than $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}n^2\right\rfloor$ cannot be obtained by some permutation, nor that only even values are reachable; neither of which is too hard to prove.